# Permission denied to access `/media/pi` folder

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, media

I connected a HDD to USB port, then Raspbian allow me to mount the unit.
So I can access to logical drive with this path: `/media/pi/PICTURES-HDD`.

Then I installed a DLNA server (serviio) to view the HDD content from TV, smartphone, notebook... etc.

The DLNA server runs as a service. The user is `dlna-user`.
The `dlna-user` has `dlna-group` as primary group, and it is member of `media` group.

So I run this command to apply required permission to allow `dlna-user` to access to the `PICTURES-HDD`:

```
# chown -R root:media /media
# chmod -R 777 /media
```

I think that it is right to permit `dlna-user` to view the `/media` folder and relative childs files and folders.

But it do not works: when I try to navigate inside the folder with `dlna-user` user I receive "Permission denied":

- change operative user:
  `$ sudo -u dlna-user hash`
  now I using the `dlna-user`.
- go to `/media` folder:
  `$ cd /media`
  it works.
- go to inside `pi` folder:
  `$ cd pi`
  returns this: `bash: cd: pi: Permission denied`.

I don't understand...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you have mount helpers which mount the storage devices with the identity of the user holding the current session on your machine. If you have a GUI and log in as `pi`, that's the user who will own the mounted devices.

Changing permissions on `/media/pi` will not achieve anything as the mount helpers will either reset the permissions or remove the folder altogether and recreate it from scratch if they find it's unusable by the `pi` user.

A common solution for mounting as a given user is to use `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=0123456789ABCDE   /mnt/pictures   ext4   defaults,uid=dlna-user,gid=dlna-group
```

You can view the UUIDs of your drive volumes using `blkid`.

The above example will mount the device automatically at boot. If this is not desired, you can add `noauto` and `user`, and later execute `mount /mnt/pictures` as `dlna-user` when you need the volume mounted.

Another option you can try is to use [`pmount`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pmount) (again, as `dlna-user`) without changing `/etc/fstab`, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: If you use `fstab` this way, the partition will be automounted at boot *normally* (by which I mean, not a `fuser` mount courtesy of the DE).  For an ext4 fs, that means unless you override them, *the permissions on the contents will be as actually set in the mounted filesystem*.  Ie., it may be preferable to **not** use `uid` and `gid`.

Comment: @goldilocks Yeah, I put the permission there in case the OP has something else for a filesystem. They may change the name but forget to put the `uid`/`gid` in.